# Is Conditional Logistic Regression Necessary for Analysis Following Matching?

Tags: multiple-regression, matching

I wanted to make sure that my approach to performing a matched case-control study is on the right track. I am looking at a group of patients who all underwent the same surgical procedure for a given disease. Initially logistic regression analysis was performed which found that there was an association between disease D and death following the procedure. I then created two groups, one with disease D (D+) and another without the disease (D-). This was done using coarsened exact matching (cem) via the `MatchIt` package in R. I matched the groups based on age, gender, race, income status, insurance type, and other comorbidities.

So now I have 2 groups (D+ and D-) with approximately 8000 patients total. I want to see if disease D, even after matching, is associated with post-procedure death. I have read that conditional logistic regression should be used in this case. My confusion stems from the fact that implementations in R for conditional logistic regression (e.g. `clogit` from the `survival` package) seem to be using cox regression (`coxph`). Why is this the case? Would it be incorrect to use unconditional logistic regression (e.g. `glm`) along with the weights created during matching? As an aside, why can't the chi-square test simply be used instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your main question about implementation, this is quoted from the clogit function help:

> It turns out that the logliklihood for a conditional logistic regresson model = loglik from a Cox model with a particular data structure. Proving this is a nice homework exercise for a PhD statistics class; not too hard, but the fact that it is true is surprising. When a well tested Cox model routine is available many packages use this ‘trick’ rather than writing a new software routine from scratch, and this is what the clogit routine does. In detail, a stratified Cox model with each case/control group assigned to its own stratum, time set to a constant, status of 1=case 0=control, and using the exact partial likelihood has the same likelihood formula as a conditional logistic regression. The clogit routine creates the necessary dummy variable of times (all 1) and the strata, then calls coxph.

So really by using a special case of Cox regression is a shortcut to performing the same analysis with existing, tested routines.